# Why my Intel Xdk Android App only works on some devices with wifi connected?

Tags: android, wifi, intel-xdk

I have an Android app that was built with jquery, html, js, etc, on Intel XDK that works fine on most devices. But I'm having some clients complaining that didn't work on his devices, if they are not connected to wifi. What would be happening here?

Comment: post relevant codes that your app requires at startup

Comment: Does you app require access to the Internet? For example, are you pulling a JS file from the Internet or using Google Maps or something similar?

Comment: Hi xmnboy. No it isn't.

Comment: I presume it does work on those devices if they are connected to wifi?  If your app doesn't require network access, then I don't know of any reason that it wouldn't work when disconnected.  Can you get any more info about the failure mode?